# Implementing save for text editor

Tags: java, text

I am building a simple text editor and i don't know how to implement save.

Should I just rewrite the file or search for differences between the previous saved file and the content about to be saved?

The first solution is obviously very easy to implement but what about its efficiency?
If the text file is big, what would be more efficient?

I suppose it depends on the changes and probably the first approach is better but I would like to hear some opinions.
What do most applications like Notepad++, Word etc. use?

Comment: If its text only, I think it's going to take *lots* of text before performance becomes an issue if you just save the entire file. Don't optimise prematurely, and any partial saving arrangement becomes complex fast.

Answer (score 1):

Usually editors anyway have to overwrite big parts of the file. Think for example at an insertion of a character at the very beginning of a file. If you make just edits inside the editor then you could keep track and save only changed parts.

UltraEdit is capable of editing really big files and uses a smarter way of saving too. But most editors will just overwrite the whole file as they commonly only are used for editing small files (< 1GB)

Hint: so I would start writing the whole file (functional) and care about the performance (non functional) later, unless it's a requirement. All in all it's a definition of what "big" means and not all files can be optimized in saving unless you change the format of the data saved.